# grails value converter for all Double

Tags: grails, double, locale

Hello I have some trouble in grails 3.1.6
I would like to save (and visualize) a double with 4 fractions digits, using the it_IT locale (I need the translation).

I make this:
1- I put in the domain class this configuration:

```
static constraints = {
value          nullable: false, scale: 4
```

2- I configured the messages_it.properties with this number format

```
default.number.format=##.####
```

3-
I tried to bind a custom ValueConverter adding it in the beans but I see that is called only on startup (getTargetType method).

```
package it.custompackage

import grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter

class DefaultDoubleConverter implements ValueConverter {

  boolean canConvert(value) {
    println(">>>>>> canConvert " + value)
    value instanceof Double
  }

  def convert(value) {
      println(">>>>>> convert " + value)
      return value
  }

  Class<?> getTargetType() {
    println(">>>>>> getTargetType ")

    return Double
  }
}
```

I'm also tried this

```
  Class<?> getTargetType() {
    println(">>>>>> getTargetType ")
    return it.package.MyClass
  }
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: This isn't related to the question you asked but having your `convert` method return `value` is going to be problematic.  The `convert` method should be converting `value` to a `Double`.

Comment: Also, your question mentions saving and visualizing.  The converter won't have any direct impact on either of those.  The converter is only involved during data binding.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug that has emerged in recent versions of the framework.  You can work around it by naming your bean `defaultGrailsDoubleConverter` (the name of the class is not relevant).